# How to debug device-specific crashes

Tags: android, flutter, crash

I'm using Flutter and recently released my app to the public. It's working well for most people, but some users have reported it crashing when reaching the home page after signing up. I checked their data in Firebase and it's clean. They have tried reinstalling and going through the initial process again, entering data that works for everyone else and it still crashes. I got the device type of two of those users and they both have the same.

How can I find out what's causing the crash for these users, without having their specific device?

Comment: no way!. until you try them out in specific device. If those devices are Chinese ones, then obviously you have to check their docs.

Comment: Make sure crashlytics implementation is working fine. also, use firebase testlab.

Comment: Android devices are hard to QA without a physical device. Manufacturers make customizations to vanilla Android then carriers sometimes require the own customizations. You can try getting the version of Android they're running, find the device hardware specs, and create an simulator profile as close as you can get. If you're unable to buy the device (check Ebay if not sold in your country) most Android devices aren't unique. You'll probably find devices with the same hardware platform and maybe only a different screen size. You can also disable the specific device in Play store console.

Comment: Crashlytics was not set up yet (I have never used it), I'm working on adding it now, and hopefully I can get more insight into the bug this way.